# What does <a class="active" href=home> mean, and how does it differ from <a href="news">News</a>

Tags: html, nav

```HTML
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="home">home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>
```

Im coding a navigation bar and I am confused to the difference of

```HTML
<a class="active" href="home">home</a>
```

compared to

```HTML
<a href="#news">News</a> .
```

Can I use `class` for the other addresses or does this have `<a` particular meaning?

Looking for an understanding of this code:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav.asp